# Java for-loop and compile error due to wrong datatype

Tags: java, arrays, list, compiler-errors, iterator

Today I had a strange experience when using a for loop in Java, which I really can't explain. That's my code snippet:

```
List<String[]> list;
....
for (String[] tmp : list.get(0)) {
...
}
```

This code snippet isn't compiling, because `list.get(0)` is returning a `String` an not an array of `String`s. But why?

Answer (score 3):

`list.get(0)` returns an array of `String`s, so when you iterate over it, you are getting individual Strings:

```
for (String tmp : list.get(0)) {
...
}
```

If you iterate over the entire list, you will get a String array in each iteration:

```
for (String[] tmp : list) {
...
}
```

Comment: It can be so simple: I really just had a error in reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate over arrays of string

```
for (String[] tmp : list) {
...
}
```

or to iterate over strings of first array

```
for (String tmp : list.get(0)) {
...
}
```

Comment: It can be so simple: I really just had a error in reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String[] tmp : list.get(0))
```

should be

```
for (String tmp : list.get(0))
```

since `list.get(0)` is an array of strings, not array of string arrays.

Comment: It can be so simple: I really just had a error in reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `list.get(0)` is not returning a `String` but a `String[]` as you expect. `List<String[]> list` is a `List` of `String[]`. `list.get(0)` therefore is a `String[]`. The problem is with your loop variable. If you loop over a `String[]`, the type of the loop variable which holds a single element during the loop is just `String`.

It should be:

```
List<String[]> list;
// ...
for (String el : list.get(0)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It can be so simple: I really just had a error in reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling list.get(0), it is returning a String array. If I extend your code it becomes like below,

```
String[] strArr = list.get(0);

....
for (String[] tmp : strArr) { //compilation issue
...
}
```

Obviously which is wrong as each object inside strArr is String, not String array.

Comment: It can be so simple: I really just had a error in reasoning. Thanks!